# REST vs SOAP WCF Service - is there a downside for using both

Tags: c#, rest, wcf, soap

When developing my WCF Service I originally planned using REST but later found out it will be called using SOAP. I have decorate my methods with both SOAP `OperationalContract` and REST `WebInvoke` but created only SOAP endpoint.

```
public interface IMyService
{

   [OperationContract]
   [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetData/{ID}/{Name}", Method = "GET",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
   string GetData(string ID, string Name);

}
```

My question is what are the possible implications of using both `OperationalContract` and `WebInvoke`, if any? Are there downsides?

Should I keep it as it is, in case later I might need to add a REST endpoint? Or should I remove `WebInvoke`?

Comment: No, there are no downsides, other than you are adding code which may never be used.

Comment: @JericCruz that "duplicate" question has almost nothing to do with what the OP has asked.

Comment: @Tom Redfern, I was thinking that by keeping REST headers I could avoid having to modify the code later, when someone wants REST instead of SOAP. This way I would just add another endpoint. Wanted to ensure that nothing could go wrong besides the fact I am keeping there extra lines of code

Comment: @Tom Redfem, could you post your comment as an answer so I could accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is what are the possible implications of using both
>   OperationalContract and WebInvoke, if any? Are there downsides?

No, there are no downsides, other than you are adding code which may never be used.

Also, for your info, OperationContract is for all WCF operations, not just for SOAP operations. You need it for REST also.